# Mongodb simple update does not work in Ruby/Mongoid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following MongoDB update operation, but it doesnt seem to work, anyone know why?

```
User.collection.update({ _id: BSON::ObjectId("5018ed448712ff240e0000a0") }, 
                       { "$set" => { name: "ben" } })
```

It does not throw an error, but just some integer which I am guessing is the doc size.

I am using Mongoid 2.4.10/Rails 3.2.7

Comment: User.collection.update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5018ed448712ff240e0000a0')}, { "$set" => {"name" => "ben" } })

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mongoid, you coule just do a find and update:

```
User.find("5018ed448712ff240e0000a0").update_attributes!(name: "ben")
```

or you could use set:

```
User.find("5018ed448712ff240e0000a0").set(:name, "ben")
```

Note that `set()` takes 2 arguments; it does not accept a hash as an argument

Answer (score 0):

Can you use mongoid API instead and use following command:

```
User.find("5018ed448712ff240e0000a0").set(name: "ben")
```